# how can I set m3u8 file content to a hls player?

Tags: javascript, m3u8, hls.js

I have an m3u8 file and i want to play with hls player. Can I set the file content into the hls player?

my m3u8 file is:

```
 #EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:51
#EXT-X-VERSION:7
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXTINF:14.2471875,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:455910@4352
https://localhost:444/api/stream/57/cHJpdmF0ZS9wcm9kdWN0LzA5LzU3NDJkY2Y3LWVjOGEtNDg5MC1hODU5LTk0MDQ1M2Y2ODdjMy5tcDM=
#EXTINF:16.93484375,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:541915@460262
https://localhost:444/api/stream/57/cHJpdmF0ZS9wcm9kdWN0LzA5LzU3NDJkY2Y3LWVjOGEtNDg5MC1hODU5LTk0MDQ1M2Y2ODdjMy5tcDM=
#EXTINF:12.96859375,
...
```

Comment: If you read [the documentation for hls.js](https://nochev.github.io/hls.js/docs/html/) you'll see that some of those tags aren't supported. I suggest you read the documentation to see how to implement the data you do have.